# WP All Import - Map value from function editor in an attribute term

Tags: php, woocommerce, wpallimport

The code below runs in function editor when I import my product sheet. How can I map the value from $result as the attribute term color?

```
<?php
// Start with an image and convert it to a palette-based image
$im = imagecreatefrompng('{shape[1]}.jpg');
imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 255);

// Search colors (RGB)
$colors = array(
    array(254, 145, 154),
    array(153, 145, 188),
    array(153, 90, 145),
    array(255, 137, 92)
);

// Loop through each search and find the closest color in the palette.
// Return the search number, the search RGB and the converted RGB match
foreach($colors as $id => $rgb)
{
    $result = imagecolorclosest($im, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
    $result = imagecolorsforindex($im, $result);
    $result = "({$result['red']}, {$result['green']}, {$result['blue']})";

    echo "#$id: Search ($rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]); Closest match: $result.\n";
}

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```